# Can a timer show in the upper-line and i can enter in lower-line in cmd?(java)

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.start();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int a = s.nextInt();    
    }
}

class Timer extends Thread {
private int a = 1;
long start = System.nanoTime();    
public void run(){
    while(a == 1){
        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.print("\r"+(int)(elapsedTime/1000000000));
    }
}
}
```

Hello everyone.I am trying to make a timer for my program and get some troubles.This is where i get so far.

With these code i can show a timer and input something but what i input will always stick with the timer.Is there are any ways to show the timer in upper-line and I can input in next line?
[What i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCwe1.png)

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I want to separate the timer and the place i input

Comment: No, you can't do that. If you want to update output *while* user is typing input, you need a GUI. You can't do that with simple command-prompt I/O.

Comment: So I can give up now.Thank you.

Comment: There are some existing, related questions. You probably want something like this: [How to constantly wait for user input while printing values in a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624222/how-to-constantly-wait-for-user-input-while-printing-values-in-a-script), and perhaps this too [How to change the contents of a line on the terminal as opposed to writing a new one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43075/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-line-on-the-terminal-as-opposed-to-writing-a-new) if you want your timer to always be on one line as opposed to a new line each time

Comment: @Andreas I disagree with your comment. You can take a look at the questions I linked to: it's perfectly possible to manipulate `System.in` and `System.out` at the same time, it just gets a little messy with how it appears in the terminal. Note of course that **technically** a non-multithreaded implementation doesn't do it at the exact same time, but to the user it will appear so because you can switch back and forth very, very fast

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver If by "gets a little messy" you mean that every time output is updated, the input typed so far becomes corrupted, and makes it virtually impossible for user to make corrections, then you're right, and I personally would find that unusable, i.e. not a valid solution = not possible while retaining useful user experience. Since presumably the updated output is to help the user, it is counter-productive to do this in a command-line app, and since changing to a GUI app with 2 panes for input and output is fairly simple, that should be the solution for this problem.

Comment: @Andreas again - I disagree. First, the input is not "corrupted" by any standard definition of the word. It's display **is** messed up in a way that I agree makes it difficult to edit. While this doesn't necessarily ruin the user experience, it is unpleasant. This could still be solved by, for example, capturing user input so far before printing to terminal, then immediately re-printing the captured input onto the input line. You're right that a GUI would be easier, but a GUI is not always a suitable replacement, and doesn't get to the question itself, which was about command line

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver *"capturing user input so far before printing to terminal"* The problem is that you can't do that *in Java*. Java doesn't see any input until user presses enter.

Comment: You probably want to use a curses library, although there doesn't seem to be a de facto Java library for it. And any such library is likely to have some cross-compatibility complexities with JNI.